# Get corrupted xls file while downloading it using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

In my current project, I used PHPExcel 1.7.8 for exporting data into excel. As per suggested I successfully configured it in my project and successfully generate xls file and stored it but when I tried to download xls file then I gor corrupted  xls file without getting any error message. I have following code for the same.

```
/** Error reporting */
if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
     die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');

/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel.php';

// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set document properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
      ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
      ->setTitle("PHPExcel Test Document")
      ->setSubject("PHPExcel Test Document")
      ->setDescription("Test document for PHPExcel, generated using PHP classes.")
      ->setKeywords("office PHPExcel php")
      ->setCategory("Test result file");

// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
         ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
         ->setCellValue('B1', 'world!')
         ->setCellValue('C1', 'Hello')
         ->setCellValue('D1', 'world!');

// Miscellaneous glyphs, UTF-8
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A2', 'Miscellaneous glyphs')
            ->setCellValue('B2', 'This is test text by me');

// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');


// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"filename.xls\"");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");

// Save Excel 2007 file
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xls', __FILE__));
$objWriter->save("php://output");
exit;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why `$objWriter->save("php://output");` ?? Where are the headers???

Comment: First rule when you get this error: open the resultant file in a text editor, and look for either whitespace or PHP error messages at the beginning and end of the file.... chances are you're getting something echoed into the php://output stream... even something as simple as a PHP BOM

Comment: Hello  All,

Thank you for reply.

After Google some links i resolved this issue by cleaning output buffer using ob_clean() function and it works for me.

Comment: @pacific i was googling this from last 24 hours , nothing work , luckily i read your comment and it worked. you should write it as an answer and accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this? Just before your

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"filename.xls\"");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
```

put `ob_end_clean();`.

There might be something wrong about your output buffer.