# Phpexcel crypted output data

Tags: phpexcel

My PHPExcel Export works and it is proper if i save the file, but when i want also make an output to the browser than i get the same file totaly crypted. 
See hardcopy:

[image]

I work on PHPExcel 1.80

Here my code:

```
    /** PHPExcel */
    require_once 'inc/phpExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    .....

    // Save Excel 2003 file
    // redirect output to client browser
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachement;filename="synt_ch_fct_export.xls"');
    //header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    $objWriter->save('img/test.xls');
```

I have searched the web, but i couldn't find any solution.
If you have an idea ???

THX in advance

Comment: Maybe `php://output` is not binary safe?  Could you try replacing `$objWriter->save('php://output');$objWriter->save('img/test.xls');` with `$objWriter->save('img/test.xls');readfile('img/test.xls');`.  That sequence of operations should be binary safe.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232020/get-corrupted-xls-file-while-downloading-it-using-phpexcel?rq=1 , even if you just have some spaced prepended in the output stream you'll also end up with a corrupted file , using ob_clean before outputting the file should solve these issues.

Comment: Hello and thank you both for your answer. It is right, i must save the file binary and also all another files include or requiered! Thans a lot en best regards